# Vaadin Flow Grid with lazy loading fetches too many rows

Tags: vaadin, lazy-loading, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

I configured a Vaadin Flow Grid with:

```
grid.setPageSize(20);

grid.setItems(q -> {
          
Page<UserSummary> page = userService.findUsers(
    dataViewFilter.getName(),
    dataViewFilter.getEmail(),
    q.getPage(), q.getPageSize());

    return page.getContent().stream();
});
```

In my test environment, I have 100 users in the database.

During the initial page load, the Grid fetches 80 users through 4 service method calls with the specified page/size:

```
0 : 20
1 : 20
2 : 20
3 : 20
```

I can see only 15-18 rows on the screen. To see others I have to scroll. How can I prevent the Grid from fetching so many rows at once? I believe having 20 or 40 records fetched from the db should suffice for the initial screen. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: The grid is always prefetching more rows than needed to allow for a smooth user scrolling experience.

Comment: Is it possible to control the number of prefetched rows?